# Playing test tones in an Javascript audio app for the web

Tags: javascript, audio, soundmanager2

For a small web app I'm making, I need to output sinusoidal test tones for client-side audio playback.

The thing is, I can't seem to find a way to do it in javascript without downloading and looping pre-rendered WAV files.

Is there a standards compliant method out there of outputting test tones? Or must I build the test tones on my own and use something like [this](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) to play back the files?

(I would much prefer to generate the test tones real-time so that I can generate a number of frequencies beyond the limited gamut of frequencies available to me with a sample set of WAV files.)

Comment: You are better off using a Java applet for this.  It isn't easily possible in Javascript, short of some really hackish methods (http://ajaxian.com/archives/generating-and-playing-sound-in-javascript).

Comment: Actually @Brad, this is exactly what I'm looking for. The data: URI scheme seems to be supported across all major browsers just enough to be worthwhile for what I'm doing. Furthermore, if I implement this technique with <a href="http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/">SoundManager 2</a> (which basically is a Flash-based fallback for HTML5 audio), it *in theory* should work fine. If you'd like to repost your answer as a suggested solution to this question, I can give it a green check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way of doing this by using the [data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#JavaScript), but it is a bit of a hack, and probably isn't very efficient.  You should also keep in mind of length limits for the data URI.

See http://ajaxian.com/archives/generating-and-playing-sound-in-javascript and http://softwareas.com/offline-sound-no-flash-no-file.